# Formally express all possible 2-tuples of a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a set
$S = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}.$

I want to express, using formal notation, a set $R$ that contains all possible 2-tuples of elements in $S$. However, no two elements of $R$ must contain the same two elements of $S$ in any order. That is, I want to express *formally* the following set that computes all possible 2-tuples from $S$ like this:

$R = \{(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)\}$

Notice that $R$ does not contain the 2-tuple $(2, 1)$, since $(1, 2)$ is already present.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I came up with the following intermediate expression:

$I = \{(x, y) \mid  x \in S \text { and } y \in S \text{ and } x \neq y\}$

However this set will give me all possible 2-tuples. From this set, I need to remove all duplicate (disregarding order) 2-tuples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [$n$-tuple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple) is ordered by definition. What you want is the collection of subsets of [cardinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality) $2$ of $S$, because it is isomorphic to non-ordered pairs.

Then you can write something like

$$R:=\{x\in\mathcal P(S):|x|=2\}$$

where $\mathcal P(S)$ is the [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of $S$, i.e. the collection of all subsets of $S$. And $|x|$ is the cardinality of the set $x$.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want the set of *two-element subsets* of $S$. (I'd avoid saying "pair", since that suggests "ordered pair," which isn't what you want based on your last sentence.)

The notation for this is "$[S]^2$" or "$[S]^{(2)}$" (I've seen both); similarly, we use "$[S]^{<\omega}$" for  the set of *finite subsets* of $S$.

Comment: That was lightning quick. Does this guarantee that no two elements of R will be duplicates? For example, does it guarantee that only one of (1, 2) and (2, 1) will be present in R?
Also, do you have any references where I can read more?

Comment: @lostsoul29 Well, $[S]^2$ is the set of two-element subsets of $S$; rather than containing either $(1, 2)$ or $(2, 1)$, it will contain $\{1, 2\}$ - note that this is the same object as $\{2, 1\}$! If you really want a set containing one of the *ordered pairs* $(1, 2)$ or $(2, 1)$ (and similarly for the other elements), then I don't know what notation to use; note that such a set isn't unique! E.g. if $S=\{1, 2\}$ we could have $R=\{(1, 2)\}$ or $R=\{(2, 1)\}$.

Comment: @lostsoul29 That said, there is a *sentence* you can write down describing the relationship between $S$ and (such an) $R$: "$R$ is a set of pairs of elements of $S$ containing exactly one of $(a, b)$ and $(b, a)$ for each distinct $a, b\in S$, and not containing $(a, a)$ for any $a\in S$." Just note that this does not describe a unique $R$ in terms of $S$, as per my previous comment.

Comment: That helps. What if I also wanted to select one unique R (any one R from all possibilities)?

Comment: @lostsoul29 Just say "$R$ has the property that . . .". I don't know a better way to do it. That said, if $S$ is **linearly ordered** by some relation $\prec$ (e.g. $S$ is a set of integers, and we use the usual ordering), then we can take $R=\{(a, b): a, b\in S, a\prec b\}$